# user running out of resources - centos

Tags: linux, centos

My centos box has starting behaving weirdly, the ssh log shows :

```
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user trading by (uid=0)
fatal: setresuid 502: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And in my cron log (for same user) I get failures

```
(CRON) ERROR (setreuid failed): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Doing ulimit -a as that user :

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 773824
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 2048
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

and limits.d 90-nproc.conf has :

```
*          soft    nproc     1024
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

But that user never seems to get more than ~20 processes when I use `ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c`, however I have not checked the  number of processes at the exact time we get the failure.

We have a small number of java services on that box, that run by the same user.  But it seems to be running out of processes ?  We also have postgres on it, but that is run as a different user.

Any tips ? Is it running out of processes due to the 1024 limit (it must be bursting at time of failures?), or am I hitting a different resource limit.

Also, when I view `/proc/{myprocid}/limits` :

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            10485760             unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             1024                 773824               processes
Max open files            100000               100000               files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       773824               773824               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Why does a process have a max number of processes ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the setting in 90-nproc.conf is to prevent fork bombs -- at least that's what the comments in my copy of that file says.

Take a look at /etc/ssh/sshd_config, specifically at the value of "MaxStartUps". Try increasing that to 1000. If that makes no difference, why not increase the value of max user processes in /etc/security/limits.conf? In the servers I manage they're set to 65535.